# why am l getting 500 internal server error in web api test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, internal-server-error

l have wrote a post api to create users

```
[HttpPost]
    public User CreateUser(User user)
    {
        //User jsonToObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user.ToString());
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The posted Model is not valid");
        }

      return user;

    }
```

when l test on postman using this json

```
{
"FirstName":"Test",
"LastName":"Test",
"Email":"test@gmail.com",
"Password":"Testerrr123"
}
```

l get 500 internal server error.Below is my model to give more insight

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date_Created { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help.l am new to coding and asp.net

Comment: `ConfirmPassword` is not set?  The easiest way to find out would be to debug your application and find out what the ModelState is.

Comment: @Jonesopolis ConfirmPassword was added to the JSON and it gave the same result.when l debugged and used postman to post a JSON it hit the modelstate breakpoint. The error messages was that the fields are required..l dont understand because l am setting them in the JSON request

Comment: so what was in the `User` object?  I'm guessing it was empty, might need `[FromBody]`

Comment: Is the post method part of a view controller ? If not can you please post the complete api ?

Comment: @AlexLeo its part of an api controller (AccountsController).. that method is the only method l have written so far for the controller.

Comment: @firefire - ok can you post the entire api controller AccountsController ?